# Rails unable to deploy new gem to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, activeadmin

so for all this while i have been deploying my web app without knowing its on production or not.
I would usually create my project as usual , where i just do the basic bundle install. and add new gems. [Setup unicorn + nginx .](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5)

And then when i view the aws's public dns, it would  show me my site as i would get on localhost:3000.

In my mind, i am still in development environment. However, it seems that when i installed a new gem , it only works on localhost:3000 but on the deployed site it self it is unrecognized. Example would be an ActiveAdmin gem , where on my site it shows "uninitialized constant ActiveAdmin" .

How should i solve this ? I am suspecting it could be because of different environments, but i am unsure how to approach this.

UPDATE  my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
#gem 'pdf-reader'
gem 'pdf-reader-turtletext'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'devise'
#gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Please post your Gemfile.

Comment: How are you deploying? What's your `Gemfile` (esp. the section containing `active_admin`)? Is your deployment running `bundle install` and restarting the `unicorn` server?

Comment: my "deployment" was just basically me just installing nginx and unicorn according to the link above.  and im unsure on how to restart my unicorn server... the examples such as sudo service restart unicorn  , are not working.

Comment: Maybe because https://github.com/activeadmin itself doesn't contain any gem, try https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin instead. Also on digitalocean. Also usually `service nginx restart` is enough to reload env.

Comment: i suspect it's my unicorn setup issue. i just recloned by project and resetup nginx and unicorn again. and woalia ! it works ! if you guys have any idea what happened , let me know.